I bought a cheap license on office 365 and I got this weird notification

What is this?
They said "my organization can install apps on my device"
Wow wow wow...
So someone can install stuffs on my computer remotely?
The username looks like
miller@xljgfwacnz.onmicrosoft.com
What is onmicrosoft.com? Is that some random domain names?
The licenses work though.
I didn't use this account in administrator account. Just local account.
I think microsoft is extremely vague here.
It uses words like my organization, or administrator without explaining which organization or administrator can have power.

Unless you completely trust the company you bought these (dubious) licenses from, be extremely cautious with any (OneDrive/Email/SharePoint) data you store in the cloud using this account. What kind of license is this?

Whenever you have a tenant with licenses attached, this popup is pretty default. But even with our own customers, I always choose the link: no, sign in to this app only. If you don't that account will be registered in windows as school/work account and that may result in problems at a later stage.

I think I click no sign in to this app only. Does that mean I am save? How do I ensure?

It's a corporate license attached to a Microsoft Azure AD (nowadays Entra ID) enterprise account – not a personal Microsoft account. Someone has made an "organization" on the Azure/Entra platform, bought (or otherwise acquired) a set of Office 365 Business licenses for the organization, and is re-selling those licenses to individuals.
The <something>.onmicrosoft.com domain is the default "test" domain that Azure AD provides for a freshly created organization. Normally one would replace it with some real corporate domain as part of the org setup, but in this case the "reseller" just smashed "xljgfwacnz" into the organization name field and left it like that.
Azure AD works similarly to traditional Active Directory, in that it allows enrolling all the corporate PCs/workstations into central management, and that's what Windows is offering here. Since you don't know who manages the domain, make sure to select "No, sign in to this app only". (Absolutely don't check the "Allow management" option, and probably best not to click "OK" either way.)
The person who created the Azure AD "organization" is the administrator. The message says "your organization" because this system was only ever meant to be used with accounts issued by an organization that you work at (or study at, etc) – it was not meant to have accounts resold – so the wording naturally assumes that you'd be getting the account from your employer (and not from some random on eBay), and the "administrator" would be your local IT Services team.

If I am not careful can the guy that sold this to me access my files?

and I don't mean files I put on one drive but any files on my computer? Can they like install backdoor in my computer?

I mean the guy is not nearby. Will this create a backdoor on my computer? I use this license in non administrator account

Creating a backdoor is pretty much the main purpose of the management feature – it's specifically made so that admins could remotely deploy any software or Windows settings to their 100+ PCs without having to walk to each one. So although they can't directly read your files through this feature, they can definitely install software that lets them read your files.

How do I ensure that they can't do that?

I disabled that license and the account isn't an administrator. Am I save?
